# How to get Vector of Complex numbers from two vectors (real & imag)

Tags: c++, stl, vector, complex-numbers

I have two vectors of floats and i want them to become one vector of Complex numbers. I'm stuck. I don't mind using iterators, but i am sure it'd be rediscovering the wheel i'm not informed about. Is my code leading me in the right direction?

```
typedef std::vector<float> CVFloat;
CVFloat vA, vB;
//fil vectors
typedef std::complex<CVFloat> myComplexVector;
myComplexVector* vA_Complex = new myComplexVector(vA, vB);
```

The code above is going through the compiler correctly, but when i want to get single numbers from myComplexVector using iterator i get error "Undefined symbol 'const_iterator'" (Borland C++)

```
myComplexVector::const_iterator it = vA_Complex->begin();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are creating a "complex" object whose real and imaginary parts are vectors of floats.
Maybe what you actually want to do is creating a vector of complex objects whose real and imaginary parts are floats?

EDIT: myComplexVector is *not* a vector, is a complex. That's why a `const_iterator` for it is not defined.

Comment: Heh, you're right of course. It works perfectly, thank you:) Sometimes it's so easy to get lost with some fake ideas.

It is part of bigger project. I optimize convultion and i have to use existing class of dft which holds real and imag vectors separately.

Answer (score 3):

Whay not do it much much easier?

```
vector< complex<float> > result;
for( int i = 0; i < vA.size(); i++ ) {
    result.push_back( complex<float>( vA[i], vB[i] ) );
}
```

Comment: Why to declare simple pair as complex in the time where complex already defined with all necessary operators overloaded?

Comment: You mean the sdt::complex class? I just had no idea it exists before you asked.

Comment: This is the right idea, but I would add two things: (a) assert(vA.size() == vB.size()); and (b) before the loop do result.resize(vA.size()); and then use result[i] = .... rather than push_back()

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make any sense:

```
typedef std::complex<CVFloat> myComplexVector;
```

surely you mean

```
typedef std::complex <float> ComplexFloat;
typedef std::vector <ComplexFloat> CFVector;
```

or something similar?

Once ou have it you can simply iterate over the float vectors (assuming they contain matching values) and add to your complex vector using push_back():

```
CFVector v;

for ( int i = 0; i < vA.size(); i++ ) {
  v.push_back( ComplexFloat( vA[i], vB[i] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just write the loop

```
myComplexVector cv;
for(CVFloat::iterator it1=vA.begin(), end1=vA.end(), 
      it2=vB.begin(), end2=vB.end();
    it1!=end1 && it2 != end2; ++it1, ++it2)
  cv.push_back(std::complex(*it1, *it2));
```

Edit: ... and follow Neil's advice to declare myComplexVector type properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a general "zip" function taking iterators to both vectors, and a convertor functor and an output iterator:

```
template< typename at_It1, typename at_It2, typename at_Transform, typename at_Out >
void zip( at_It1 from1, const at_It1 to1, 
          at_It2 from2, const at_It2 to2,
          at_Transform  tranformer,
          at_Out& av_Out ) {
    while( from1 != to1 ) {
        av_Out = transformer( *from1, *from2 );
        ++av_Out; ++from1; ++from2;
    }
}

struct DoubleToComplex {
     complex<double> operator()( const double d1, const double d2 ) const {
         return complex<double>( d1, d2 );
     }
};



zip( vA.begin(), vA.end(),
     vB.begin(), vB.end(),
     DoubleToComplex(),
     std::back_inserter( vTarget ) );
```

And I wish there were such a function in the STL...

Comment: Meanwhile we're way past 2017, and, we have `std::transform(begin(vA), end(vA), begin(vB), [](auto a, auto b){ return complex(a, b); }, std::back_inserter(vTarget));`

Answer (score 0):

A complex number is simply a pair of two real numbers `a` and `b` which denote the complex number `a+bi`. What exactly are you trying to do with the two vectors?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question that you want to combine a vector of real parts with a vector of imaginary parts into a vector of complex numbers.

`std::complex` has one template parameter which lets you chose the numerical represenation of the parts of the complex (i.e. if you want complex values based on `double` or `float` or even some custom number type...). The complex type then defines basic complex algebra in terms of the underlying type.

In your code you are trying to construct a complex type based on a vector of floats (i.e. a *single* complex value having a real and imaginary part being a vector), which is obviously wrong. Instead you want a *vector of complex numbers of type float*

You'd have to do something like:

```
// ...
typedef std::vector<std::complex<float> > floatComplexVector;
floatComplexVector vA_Complex; // No need to 'new' !?

for (CVFLoat::const_iterator itA = vA.begin(), itB = vB.begin(); 
     itA != vA.end() && itB != vB.end(); 
     ++itA,++itB)
  vA_Complex.push_back(std::complex<float>(*itA, *itB));
```

*Remarks:*

- In most cases it isn't necessary to create containers such as vectors on the heap (i.e. using `new`) Try to avoid this.
- Unfortunately the C++ standard library doesnt contain a combining iterator (i.e. one that "automatically" combines two sequences) which would allow a more elegant solution (see [Boost Zip iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) for a general idea).