# How to put real and imaginary components into one variable like in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

I have successfully computed the hilbert transform of a vector of floats. The output of this transform has the real components in `out2[i][0]`, and the imaginary components in `out2[i][1]`. The problem is, I need to be able to divide as follows: `[(out2[i][0] + out2[i][1]*I)/(out2[i-1][0] + out2[i-1][1]*I)]`. The matlab equivalent of the hilbert transform spits out the results in the form

> > 0.0440 - 0.0876i
> >
> > 0.0740 - 0.0309i
> >
> > 0.0790 - 0.0097i
> >
> > 0.0490 + 0.0458i

and I am trying to replicate the results in that form so that I can divide for example (0.0440 - 0.0876i)/(0.740-0.0309i).

My most recent attempt was based off of [How to get Vector of Complex numbers from two vectors (real & imag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681192/how-to-get-vector-of-complex-numbers-from-two-vectors-real-imag)
 and was able to get the results to be in the following (real component, imaginary component) form:

> > (25.6853,12.4197)
> >
> > (28.315,38.7512)
> >
> > (24.6848,23.5361)
> >
> > (1.31542,62.6511)

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I should go about doing this?

Comment: @rayryeng Why? He can just use [std::complex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)

Comment: @rayryeng Why? [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_arith) has it.

Comment: C++ have a [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) class, declare that as a variable and you have both real and imaginary parts in a single variable.

Comment: I removed my comment once I figured that out for myself.  Thanks guys!  Teaches me that I should probably do a search before putting a stupid comment like that.

Comment: The question is how OP didn't find it. If you have two `std::complex` variables, why not just try writing `cpl1/cpl2`? And OP does use `std::complex` if they used the answer they linked. I am not sure what the question is about.

Comment: @luk32 - I'm not sure.  Probably didn't read it properly.  I also removed my comment once I saw that link.  I also wasn't aware of `std::complex`.  Maybe the OP wants to not use `std::complex` and wants to get it done with arrays, and is using that answer as inspiration.

Comment: @luk32 Yea, I have tried to use std::complex before, but due to my lack of c++ and coding knowledge in general I did not completely understand how to use it or that it would even work for this application. I had been focused on getting the results in the exact `real+imag*i` form that matlab has, without realizing that it isn't necessary to get that exact form as long as the operations work out the same. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex numbers support the `/` operation:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_arith3